# wormhole attack in ns2 using aodv protocol

Tags: linux

I am trying to implement wormhole attack in ns2 using aodv....I started project and i was not able to build the tunnel by using packet encapsulation.. I would like to know any one has implemented it using packet encapsulation.... I have looked around the internet for source code on this, but have found none. Does anyone know where to find source code for Wormhole sensor Attacks (for simulation purposes) or wormhole detection? any help on this issue is appreciated.

Looking forward for your help,
Shreyas

Comment: What do you have so far? [mcve]. Greetings not appreciated.